# MVC image folder not accessible from Home/Contact but visible from Home/Index in _Layouts.cshtml

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have created an MVC4 project and set up my _Layout.cshtml with the relevant links for the site and an image but the images are not being displayed from the contact us page. My code for the images is as follows:

```
<a href="meta-index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="MetaAwareness" title="MetaAwareness" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the relative path to `images` folder. You likely have `Index` action and `Home` controller as default parameter values in a `Default` route. Therefore, the url that will invoke this action probably does not have controller and action included. Assuming that `images` folder is in website root directory, the relative path `images` takes us to the correct location. In case of `Home/Contact` url, same relative path would mean `Home/Contact/images` folder which does not exist.

Use:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/[path to images dir from website root dir (usually - content)]/images/logo.png") %>" ...
```

Realized that you use Razor:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/logo.png")" ...
```